# 'Can't you roll the dice' meaning in lyric of Still standing by The Rasmus

Tags: meaning-in-context

The quoted text is part of the lyrics from the song *Still standing* by The Rasmus.
It's about friend who died.

> Cause I've been down
>   Now I've been crawling
>   Won't get down no more
>   Can't you stop the lies
>   Falling from the skies
>   Down on me
>   I'm still standing
>   **Can't you roll the dice
>  
>   I might be surprised**
>   Conscience clear
>   I'm still standing here

By and large, the meaning of this song is very difficult to understand. 
But most of all, the part **can't you roll the dice / I might be surprised**

According to the dictionary, **roll the dice** means taking risk.

How I understand that part in lyrics context?

You can read the complete lyrics [here](https://genius.com/The-rasmus-still-standing-lyrics)

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of **to roll the dice**  is to cast those cubes with dots on them, representing numbers, as in a game of chance. Each cube is called a **die** and **dice** is the plural form.  Figuratively the phrase means "to take a risk, to gamble".

Any more than that we cannot say here, as interpretation of lyrics and poems is considered off-topic on this site. That said, you have reason to be confused, as those lyrics are rather unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of examples in literature about the gods playing games that involve us poor humans. In the Discworld series by Sir Terry Pratchett, the scene has been narrated multiple times.

That said, what about this idea: Let's suppose that the departed friend is in heaven by the gods' playing table. Possibly the song writer has been having bad luck in the game, a metaphor for being a bit depressed by his friend's death, and he is requesting that friend to **roll the dice** for him. He's pesimistic about the result but **he might be suprised** by a turn in his fortune, let's **take the chance**.